# CodedUI testing on a large number of VMs in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, coded-ui-tests

The subject line is what I am looking to accomplish in a nutshell. The testing is for a Windows client that connects to a locally hosted server. I need the CodedUI test to run on as many VMs as possible.

I am new to Azure and all of the terminology associated with it, but have been doing a bit of research and it looks like Azure Pipelines may help me accomplish what I need.  My company's Azure admin is not familiar with Pipelines and has asked if I may need to use the Microsoft administered Azure DevOps for that.

I am hoping that someone who knows what they're talking about could help me with this. Is what I am trying to do feasible? What are all the pieces that I will need? Is there an upper limit on how many VMs I can run a test on simultaneously?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure DevOps Pipelines can help you accomplish this. There are some considerations though.

The standard way to UI test a web app would be to create a build that includes your app and tests, then create a new release definition with the built-in "Visual Studio Test" tasks, and run the release on a number of Microsoft-hosted agents (VMs).

First problem, since you are using a windows client, Microsoft-hosted agents probably won't work because they don't have connectivity to your network. You can use self-hosted agents, but that means you have VMs to manage now.

Second problem, pricing is not based on minutes, but on number of concurrent jobs. If you want to be able to run tests on 20 agents at once, you have to pay for 20 concurrent jobs, even if you only run your tests for 5 minutes a month.

Putting on my creative thinking hat... Here's a solution that would work with a single Microsoft-hosted agent. You could create an ARM template that does the following:

- Stand up as many VMs as you want
- Use VM extensions and Powershell DSC and/or other scripts to configure the VM (You can install Windows features, connect to your domain, install Chrome, etc)
- Run powershell scripts to download your application, configuration, and testing tools from somewhere (ex. file server or azure storage), then run your tests and publish the results

Your release pipeline would deploy the ARM template to a new resource group, wait, and then delete everything when the tests are done.

This solution has the benefit of running on VMs in your network without making you maintain or pay for VMs long term.